# How to display two images on the same Tkinter Toplevel () window

Tags: python, image, tkinter, listbox, global-variables

So I'm building an app which has the option to compare two photos. I put a listbox on the left side of the screen, and a place for the two photos on the right side of the screen. There are three buttons under the listbox which are used to place pictures under a certain title (Pic 1 or Pic 2). It works, but I can only put one photo on both Pic 1 and Pic 2 - if I select one photo and put it under Pic 1, then select another photo and put it under Pic 2, the first one dissappears.

For a better understanding of my problem, here is the photo browse function from my app.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

def photo_browse ():

    def add_photo (screen, column_num):

        if not "pic" in globals ():
            tkMessageBox.showerror ("Error!", "No picture selected!")
            screen.lift ()
        else:
            screen.image = pic
            can = Label (screen, image = pic)
            can.grid (row = 0, column = column_num)
            Label (screen, text = chosen_photo).grid (row = 1, column = column_num)

    def selection_listbox (evt):

        global chosen_photo
        chosen_photo = str (photo_listbox.get (photo_listbox.curselection ()))
        image_location = "Pics/" + chosen_photo
        global pict
        pict = Image.open (image_location)
        global pic
        pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage (pict)

    import glob

    photo_browse_screen = Toplevel ()
    photo_browse_screen.title ("Photo browse")
    photo_browse_screen.geometry ("1000x600")
    photo_browse_screen.resizable (0, 0)
    photo_listbox = Listbox (photo_browse_screen, width = 50, height = 35)
    photo_listbox.grid (columnspan = 3)
    photo_listbox.bind ('<<ListboxSelect>>', selection_listbox)
    name_list = glob.glob ("Pics/*.jpg")
    name_list = [i [6:] for i in name_list]
    name_list.sort ()
    n = 1
    m = 0
    for i in name_list:
        photo_listbox.insert (n, name_list [m])
        n += 1
        m += 1
    Button (photo_browse_screen, text = "PIC 1", command = lambda: add_photo (photo_browse_screen, 4)).grid (row = 1, column = 0)
    Button (photo_browse_screen, text = "PIC 2", command = lambda: add_photo (photo_browse_screen, 5)).grid (row = 1, column = 1)
    Button (photo_browse_screen, text = "EXIT", command = photo_browse_screen.destroy).grid (row = 1, column = 2)
    can_pic_1 = Label (photo_browse_screen, text = "Pic 1", font= "-weight bold")
    can_pic_1.grid (row = 0, column = 4, padx = (200, 100), sticky = N)
    can_pic_2 = Label (photo_browse_screen, text = "Pic 2", font= "-weight bold")
    can_pic_2.grid (row = 0, column = 5, padx = (100, 150), sticky = N)

root = Tk ()
root.title ("Main menu")
root.geometry ("1000x600")
root.resizable (0, 0)
main_menu = Menu (root)

photos_menu = Menu (main_menu, tearoff = 0)

main_menu.add_cascade (label = "Photos", menu = photos_menu)
photos_menu.add_command (label = "Browse photos", command = photo_browse)

root.config (menu = main_menu)

root.mainloop ()
```

In a previous function (add photos) I resize photos to 308x440 dimension so they fit in this window perfectly.

After reviewing my code, I am almost positive that `global` variables are causing this problem, so if anyone can offer an alternative, I would be grateful.

Comment: Have you tried putting them in separate containers like frames?

Comment: I haven't... How can I do that? As far as I know, Frame doesn't have the option that puts an image in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using python 3.4 so i'm not 100% sure this will work for you (for me Tkinter is tkinter)

When I want to use multiple images I add them all to a list, you don't need to do anything with the list after that

This has always worked for me and I have the same problem you described without a list

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

global all_images
all_images = []

def photo_browse ():
    def selection_listbox (evt):    
        global chosen_photo
        chosen_photo = str (photo_listbox.get (photo_listbox.curselection ()))
        image_location = "Pics/" + chosen_photo
        global pict
        pict = Image.open (image_location)
        global pic
        pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage (pict)

        # adding all the images to a list has worked for me in the past
        global all_images
        all_images = all_images + [chosen_photo, pic, pict]
```

Comment: it works very fine, thank you! I'm still a beginner in this, but with this example I saw the problems global variables may cause, and I will do my best to avoid them in the future!